# Angular: transfer data with $scope

Tags: angularjs

Really have no idea why this doesn't work. I must be doing something incredibly stupid.

Here is a controller:

```
angular.module('nightlifeApp')
    .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.testvar = 'before';
        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.testvar = 'after';
        }, 2000);
    });
```

and here is the view that has this as the controller:

```
h1(ng-bind='testvar')
h1 {{testvar}}
```

But neither h1 element ever changes! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `setTimeout` then you manually need to trigger `apply`. Like

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

```
setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.testvar = 'after';
      });
}, 2000);
```

In my opinion you should use `$timeout` service. So it will trigger `$apply()` automatically. Your code will look like

```
$timeout(function () {
   $scope.testvar = 'after';
}, 2000);
```

Make sure you've injected `$timeout` service in your controller. In your HTML you don't need to use `ng-bind`. You're doing same in controller. Only

```
<h1> {{testvar}} </h1>
```

Comment: I was just using setTimeout as an example to change something, as this problem is occurring in a larger project. Using $timeout as you showed above still does not change anything.

Comment: check my edited answer. In your template you're over riding `testvar` varibale with `null`. Please update your HTML

Comment: Okay I figured it out, I was never injecting a root scope in my main.controller.spec.js file, so there was never a scope to begin with!

Comment: @RyanMarren.. you can also try injecting $timeout service in your controller.